# why is error is coming while debugging the code

Tags: python, debugging

I am solving some problems. When I compile and run the code.It gets successfully executed.But when i try to run this in debugging mode this throws me an error while giving the input in the console.

[here is the screenshot for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F3WJ.jpg)

```py
for i in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    list1=list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]
    count=0
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        if(10<=list1[j] and list1[j]<=60):
            count=+1
    print(count)
```

below is the error I am getting when I try to give the values in the debug mode.

```py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.6777.52)
>>>3
PyDev console: starting.
3
>>>2
2
>>>12 22
  File "<input>", line 1
    12 22
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>12 22
```

seems to be an invalid input. The problem is not in the code, but in your input.